# vs-code notebooks output font size too small

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-lab

In the new version of VScode(1.60.0), they added a lot of stuff for notebooks support.
When i try to run the code, the output font size is too small.
My zoom setting on vscode is set to -0.5. Making it 0 makes the output a little better but then the input size is too big and individual cell size is also too large.
Does anyone know what might be causing the font size to be different?

[screenshot showcasing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN0tx.png)

Comment: I share similar pain. I spent a lot of time researching how to change the font size and the encounter solution doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font-size can be changed in the next version of vscode - v1.67 - with this setting:

Maybe these two new settings in vscode v1.67 will help:

> `notebook.outputFontSize`  Font size for plain text outputs. When set
> to 0 `editor.fontSize` is used.
>
> `notebook.outputFontFamily` The font family for plain text output of
> notebook cells. When set to empty, the `editor.fontFamily` is used.

- from https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/147321/commits/51ab78f535d8537e031e1ae77cac678ae22b0249